# programmatically creating a remote directory using ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, directory

Using a shell script, how can I create a directory remotely from serverA -> serverB using ssh? Can I pass the create directory command with the ssh command? How?

I'm basically looking to create a directory remotely based on date (ex. 20110304), if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 12):

```
ssh remote-host-ip '. ~/your_profile; mkdir your_directory'
```

don't know what you mean exactly by "by date", but you could test before mkdir as below

```
ssh remote-host-ip '. ~/your_profile; test -d your_directory || mkdir your_directory'
```

if you want a directory name as you mention, try

```
ssh remote-host-ip '. ~/your_profile; test -d your_parent_directory/$(date +%Y%M%d) || mkdir your_parent_directory/$(date +%Y%M%d)'
```

Comment: Select your code and press CTRL+K to turn on code highlighting or optionally surround them in backticks `` if you want to highlight inline `like` so

Comment: Should this `. ~/your_profile;` something like this `. ~/.bash_profile` ? @SOUser

Answer (score 11):

you can accomplish it like this:

```
  ssh you@serverB "mkdir /path/to/dir"
```

or If you have a script on serverA....

```
  ssh you@serverB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

Comment: also if you need bash to load your environment, you can use `bash --login`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a date programmatically, take a look at `date +format`:

```
jinx:774 Z$ date +%m%d%H%M
03041904
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh user@server mkdir path/$(date +%Y%m%d)`

You need to setup password less authentication between the servers for this to work.
[Here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) are the steps to do that.